# Как узнать в какой элемент было перемещение?

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте!

Если на странице есть множество элементов, к которым применен плагин jQuery [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/), как определить в какой из них был помещен элемент?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Елемент, в который был помещен другой элемент, присваивается в this функции drop:

```
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui)
    {
        /* $(this) - элемент в который был помещен другой элемент*/
        /* ui.draggable - элемент который перенесли */
    }
});
```

Comment: Во! Точняк :) Перепутал ui с this :)

Answer (score 0):

Точно не помню, но 100% нужно посмотреть firebug'ом эти две переменных: event, ui

Они передаются в функцию drop по окончанию дропа. По-моему у ui есть переменная, которая хранит в себе дропа. Опять же - смотрите firebug'ом.